# Dynamically insert rows and columns - React Native

Tags: image, react-native

## What I would like to have happen

**I would like my app to organize `x` number of photos in rows of three.**

For example if I have nine images, I would like to be able to have them placed like this:

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
```

Now If I have 12 images I would like them to be placed like this:

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
XXX
```

And for two images:

```
XX
```

And so on and so forth.

## What I have tried

## First try

With no styling the images pop up like this:

```
X
X
X
X
X
```

## Second try

And if I use `{flexDirection: 'row'}` they pop up like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Even after they have left the screen.

## Third Try

I tried using a for loop to loop through every third photo, but it complained that there was no closing/opening `View`:

```
if (x % 3 === 0) {
  return (
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Image
        />
  )
}else {
  return (
      <Image
      />
  )
}
```

This way also does not work because I do not know if the number of photos will be a multiple of three, and if they aren't I have no way of closing the `View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting `flexDirection: row`, then using `flexWrap` [as documented here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap). What it will do is treat the Views like your second attempt, but when there's not enough room for the next image, it will bring it down to the next row.

This will allow you to create a more responsive application as if there is more or less screen space (small phone versus large phone), you can have more or less on each row for the ideal experience.